# grep commad is not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, search, grep, cut

I am trying to extract the value from

in File.txt :

> 116206K->13056K(118080K), 0.0879950
>   secs][Tenured:274796K->68056K(274892K),
>   0.2713740 secs] 377579K->68056K(392972K), [Perm
>   :17698K->17604K(17920K)], 0.3604630
>   secs]

I have try to extract

```
cat File.txt | grep 'Perm '| cut -d',' -f3|cut -d'(' -f2 |cut -d')' -f 1
```

What is wrong here . because i am trying I am getting the

392972K  which  is from 377579K->68056K(392972K)

But i should get from [Perm :17698K->17604K(17920K)] **17920**

Comment: remark: `cat file | grep` is a **useless use of cat** (*UUOC*). Use `grep 'Perm' file` instead, it costs one less process.

Comment: This is only for test .. I have different reason why I am doing that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One quick fix, change `-f3` to `-f4` as the field you need appears ***after*** the 3rd comma:

```
cat File.txt | grep 'Perm '| cut -d',' -f4|cut -d'(' -f2 |cut -d')' -f 1
                                        ^^
```

You can also use `sed` as:

```
grep 'Perm' File.txt | sed -r 's/.*Perm :.*\((.*?)\).*/\1/'
```

[Working link](http://www.ideone.com/5dPrt)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -vFS="->" '{gsub(/)].*|.*\(/,"",$5);print $5}' file1
17920K
```